24.04 GUI not working after upgrade from 22.04
I have an AWS EC2 ubuntu instance I upgraded from 22.04 LTS to 24.04.1 LTS but still can't connect GUI

Try the following.
Open a terminal
Run in it
exec sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt -f install
apt -m install
apt dist-upgrade
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt autoremove
apt clean
exit
sudo reboot

If any command gives error continue running the following and repeat the commands.
