Removed libgl1-mesa-dri by accident
Python reported a problem with MESA-Loader so I and ran the following commands on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (to be honest, I did not really know what I was doing):
dpkg -l | grep mesa
sudo apt remove --purge libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo apt install libglu1-mesa
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo apt install mesa-utils

Now, I am only seing the command line and no graphical interface on the machine.
All I want is getting back the graphical interface (reverting above commands)
What I tried:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo apt install mesa-utils
sudo reboot

Which did not help.
When I do dpkg -l | grep mesa I get:
ii libegl-mesa0:amd64                24.0.9.-0ubuntu0.2    amd64  ...
ii libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64             24.0.9.-0ubuntu0.2    amd64  ...
ii libglapi-mesa:amd64               24.0.9.-0ubuntu0.2    amd64  ...
ii libglu1-mesa:amd64                9.0.2-1.1build1       amd64  ...
ii libglx-mesa0:amd64                24.0.9.-0ubuntu0.2    amd64  ...
ii mesa-utils                        9.0.0-2               amd64  ...
ii mesa-utils-bin:amd64              9.0.0-2               amd64  ...
ii mesa-va-drivers:amd64             24.0.9.-0ubuntu0.2    amd64  ...
ii mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64          24.0.9.-0ubuntu0.2    amd64  ...
ii mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64         24.0.9.-0ubuntu0.2    amd64  ...


Try the following:    https://askubuntu.com/questions/1531614/24-04-gui-not-working-after-upgrade-from-22-04

@kyodake's comment was the solution. Basically,
exec sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt -f install
apt -m install
apt dist-upgrade
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt autoremove
apt clean
exit
sudo reboot

solved my problem! :)
